# Is it possible to parse encrypted Ansible vault values from a dynamic inventory in a playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-vault

I have a dynamic inventory set up which pulls hosts and their variables from a MySQL database. The dynamic inventory itself is working perfectly.

Some of the variables inside the inventory are sensitive so I would prefer not to store them as plain text.

So as a test I encrypted a value using:

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string 'foobar'
```

Which resulted in:

```
!vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          39653264643032353830336333356665663638353839356162386462303338363661333564633737
          3737356131303563626564376634313865613433346438630a343534363066393431633366393863
          30333636386536333166363533373239303864633830653566316663616432633336393936656233
          6633666134306530380a356664333834353265663563656162396435353030663833623166363466
          6436
Encryption successful
```

I decided to store the encrypted value as a variable inside MySQL. For the avoidance of doubt, after some testing, you can normalise the encrypted string to:

```
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
363635393063363466313636633166356562396562336633373239333630643032646637383866656463366137623232653531613135623464353932653665300a376461666332626538386263343732333039356663363132333533663339313466346435373064343931383536393736303731393834323964613063323362370a3361313132396239336130643839623939346438616363383932616639656463
```

You can test this format works with a simple playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all

  gather_facts: no
  
  vars:
    final_var: !vault "$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256\n363635393063363466313636633166356562396562336633373239333630643032646637383866656463366137623232653531613135623464353932653665300a376461666332626538386263343732333039356663363132333533663339313466346435373064343931383536393736303731393834323964613063323362370a3361313132396239336130643839623939346438616363383932616639656463"

  tasks:
    - name: Display variable
      debug:
        msg: "{{ final_var }}"
```

When the playbook is executed the following output is observed:

```
ok: [target] => {
    "msg": "foobar"
}
```

The difficulty arises when trying to get the variable (`my_secret`) from the inventory instead of referencing it directly in a file.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all

  gather_facts: no
  
  vars:
    final_var: !vault "{{ my_secret }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Display variable
      debug:
        msg: "{{ final_var }}"
```

This results in:

```
fatal: [target]: FAILED! => {"msg": "input is not vault encrypted data"}
```

Now, while I've spoken a lot about the value being stored in the dynamic inventory in MySQL we can get a similar behaviour if we remove that from the equation.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all

  gather_facts: no
  
  vars:
    secret: "$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256\n363635393063363466313636633166356562396562336633373239333630643032646637383866656463366137623232653531613135623464353932653665300a376461666332626538386263343732333039356663363132333533663339313466346435373064343931383536393736303731393834323964613063323362370a3361313132396239336130643839623939346438616363383932616639656463"
    final_var: !vault "{{ secret }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Display variable
      debug:
        msg: "{{ final_var }}"
```

This is now nearly identical to the working example but the encrypted string is not written inline but instead coming from another variable.

This results in the same error:

```
fatal: [target]: FAILED! => {"msg": "input is not vault encrypted data"}
```

This may indicate that the wider problem is that Ansible is for some reason unable to parse encrypted data stored as a variable. Perhaps when the YAML is being parsed it is literally trying to decrypt `"{{ my_secret }}"` rather than `$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256 ...`.

Which kind of makes sense but I wanted to run that past you guys and ask if there is a way around this or if you recommend a different approach entirely. Thanks.

Comment: just curios why are not saving `!valut` in your secret? why are you separating this particular piece from generated encrypted string?

Comment: `!vault` is part of the YAML syntax itself Ansible uses rather than part of the encrypted string. It tells Ansible that what follows is an encrypted string. If it was part of the encrypted string Ansible would read it literally as a plain string and wouldn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be better off putting the variables into the encrypted files. Store the encrypted files in MySQL instead of encrypted variables. If you already *"have a dynamic inventory set up which pulls hosts and their variables from a MySQL database"* there shouldn't be a problem to modify the setup. Pull the encrypted files from the database and store them in host_vars (and/or group_vars, play vars, role vars ...) instead of storing encrypted variables in the inventory (and/or in the code of playbook, role, ...). This way, in the code, you don't care whether a variable is encrypted or not.

For example

```yaml
shell> tree host_vars/
host_vars/
├── test_01
│   └── final_var.yml
├── test_02
│   └── final_var.yml
└── test_03
    └── final_var.yml

shell> cat host_vars/test_01/final_var.yml 
final_var: final_var for test_01

shell> cat host_vars/test_02/final_var.yml 
final_var: final_var for test_02

shell> cat host_vars/test_03/final_var.yml 
final_var: final_var for test_03
```

Encrypt the files. For example

```sh
shell> ansible-vault encrypt host_vars/test_01/final_var.yml
Encryption successful

shell> cat host_vars/test_01/final_var.yml
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
37363965336263366466336236336466323033353763656262633836323062626135613834396435
3665356363396132356131663336396138663962646434330a346433353039383864333638633462
35623034363338356362346133303262393233346439363264353036386337356236336135626434
6533333864623132330a346566656630376439643533373263303338313063373239343463333431
62353230323336383263376335613635616339383934313164323938363066616136373036326461
3538613937663530326364376335343438366139366639303230
```

Then the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: test_01,test_02,test_03
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}: {{ final_var }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
    "msg": "test_02: final_var for test_02"
    "msg": "test_01: final_var for test_01"
    "msg": "test_03: final_var for test_03"
```

Comment: Took a while for me to get back to this but I really appreciate your help. This is the approach I'm going to go with hence I've marked yours as the accepted answer. Thanks again!