# Dynamically fetching passwords from ansible-vault in a playbook

Tags: ansible, passwords, ansible-inventory, ansible-vault

I struggle with fetching a variable from vault file. I know there are many useful information here on stackoverflow already. The reason for opening a new question is because it's a special workflow in my playbook. I'm open for constructive critic to my solution, if you have better ideas.

The vault has a var defined called passwort_abc. This variable is not always defined. If it's not it should generate a new password. I face the situation, that it's never fetched and always generated newly and it fails at the `DEBUG existing_secret` with following error message:

```py
fatal: [abc.domain.net]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. 
The error was: {{ pw_key_from_vault }}: 
{{ vars['passwort_' + host] }}: 'dict object' has no attribute 'passwort_abc'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'passwort_abc'. 
{{ vars['passwort_' + host] }}: 'dict object' has no attribute 'passwort_abc'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'passwort_abc'. 
{{ pw_key_from_vault }}: {{ vars['passwort_' + host] }}: 'dict object' has no attribute 'passwort_abc'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'passwort_abc'. 
{{ vars['passwort_' + host] }}: 'dict object' has no attribute 'passwort_abc'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'passwort_abc'

The error appears to be in './deploy_postgresql.yaml': line 11, column 7, but may be 
elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

pre_tasks:
   - name: DEBUG existing_secret
     ^ here\n"}
```

## let me show and explain you the code...

-> For explanation purposes, I reproduced the issues with this code and steps:

- `Deploy something` the playbook "loads" all required vars_files and afterwards
- `DEBUG existing_secret` should print the "existing_secret" from vault file if a related secret is found in the vault file
- `GENERATE special_secret or fetch from vault_file` create the special_secret variable: in case existing_variable is define use it, otherwise default to generate_secret_string. This is how I handle the case when no variable in existing_secret is set.
- `DEBUB special_secret` should print the "special_secret" which was generated before.

### playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Deploy something
  hosts: abc.domain.net, klm.domain.net, xyz.domain.net
  vars_files:
    - /path/to/vault.yaml
    - /path/to/vars.yaml
  pre_tasks:
    - name: DEBUG existing_secret
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ existing_secret | d('I don't have any secret to show yet') }}"

    - name: "GENERATE special_secret or fetch from vault_file"
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        special_secret : "{{ existing_secret | default(generate_secret_string) }}"

    - name: DEBUB special_secret
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ special_secret }}"
```

### vars file

```yaml
---
hostname: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
host: "{{ hostname | regex_replace('^(.*?).domain.net$', '\\1') }}"
pw_key_from_vault: "{{ vars['passwort_' + host] }}"
existing_secret: "{{ pw_key_from_vault }}"
generate_secret_string: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.password','/dev/null length=30 chars=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!§$@&/()=#+?_.,') }}"
```

explanation to `host` it's a variable from vars_file which is regexed and output eigther abc or xyz so we and up with a variable name like `passwort_abc or passwort_xyz`, which then should match the variable from the vault_file.

### vault file

```yaml
---
passwort_abc: supersecretabc
passwort_xyz: supersecretklm
```

## expectations

1. The variable get's fetched from vault_file correctly if exists.
2. If the variable in vault_file is missing - generate a new. (it should be processed or written back to vault.
   just the split between those to steps is primarily enough.

## what has been checked already

- [How to get password from ansible vault to be used as variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210077/how-to-get-password-from-ansible-vault-to-be-used-as-variable)
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-vault-to-protect-sensitive-ansible-data
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/index.html
- [Is it possible to parse encrypted Ansible vault values from a dynamic inventory in a playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65036796/is-it-possible-to-parse-encrypted-ansible-vault-values-from-a-dynamic-inventory)

Comment: Change the line `msg: "{{ existing_secret }}"` in your first debug to `msg: "{{ existing_secret | d('I don't have any secret to show yet') }}"`. The host without a secret will stop erroring and since it will go on with the next tasks, all the rest is then working as expected.

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for the hint! that helped the script to process but still doesn't fix the issue why this variable is not fetched correctly from vault_file. (the variable exist, but just don't get read correctly)

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/bc1f16334359fde1a93698ece7ea3fea)

Comment: @Zeitounator yes you were right! you're solution helped me a lot! The other problem was that I haven't used an absolute path for `path/to/vault.yaml` instead I used a variable which was declared in vars.yaml... therefore the existing_secret was always empty.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint from @Zeitounator, the answer to this solution is:

to avoid this weird error message when the variable is undefined or can't be retrieved from the vault: `{{ existing_secret | d('I don't have any secret to show yet') }}`

As well as you have to directly include/load vars from vault by using vars_file.
This code now is solving the issue and is adjusted.

Thanks for the help!